# center multi-line text in python output

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, output, string-formatting

OK, so this seems like a really basic question, but I can't find a workable answer anywhere, so here goes.

I have some text:

```
text = '''
Come and see the violence inherent in the system. Help! Help! I'm being 
repressed! Listen, strange women lyin' in ponds distributin' swords is no 
basis for a system of government. Supreme executive power derives from a 
mandate from the masses, not from some farcical aquatic ceremony. The Lady 
of the Lake, her arm clad in the purest shimmering samite held aloft 
Excalibur from the bosom of the water, signifying by divine providence that 
I, Arthur, was to carry Excalibur. THAT is why I am your king.'''
```

It doesn't contain any line breaks or other formatting. 
I want to wrap my text so it displays properly in my ipython output window when I run my code. I also want it centered, and a bit shorter than the full window width (80 chars)

If I had a short text string (shorter than the line length) I could simply calculate the length of the string and pad it with spaces to get it to centre, or use the `text.center()` property to display it correctly.

If I had a text string that I just wanted to wrap, I could use:

```
from textwrap import fill
print(fill(text, width=50))
```

and set width to whatever

So I would have thought I could simply then:

```
from textwrap import fill
wrapped_text = (fill(text, width=50))
print(wrapped_text.center(80))
```

but it doesn't work. Everything is still left justified.

I'm sure I can't be the only person who has tried to do this. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `center` expects a single-line string, and [`fill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill) returns a multiline string.

The answer is to `center` each line, before joining them up.

If you look at the docs for `fill`, it's shorthand for:

```
"\n".join(wrap(text, ...))
```

So, you can just skip that shorthand and use `wrap` directly. For example, you can write your own function that does exactly what you want:

```
def center_wrap(text, cwidth=80, **kw):
    lines = textwrap.wrap(text, **kw)
    return "\n".join(line.center(cwidth) for line in lines)

print(center_wrap(text, cwidth=80, width=50))
```

Although if you're only doing this in one place, to immediately print it out, it's probably simpler to not even bother `join`ing it:

```
for line in textwrap.wrap(text, width=50):
    print(line.center(80))
```

Answer (score 3):

`wrapped_text` is a list of strings so loop over the strings and center them.

```
import textwrap

text = "Come and see the violence inherent in the system. Help! Help! I'm being repressed! Listen, strange women lyin' in ponds distributin' swords is no basis for a system of government. Supreme executive power derives from a mandate from the masses, not from some farcical aquatic ceremony. The Lady of the Lake, her arm clad in the purest shimmering samite held aloft Excalibur from the bosom of the water, signifying by divine providence that I, Arthur, was to carry Excalibur. THAT is why I am your king."    

wrapped_text = textwrap.wrap(text)
for line in wrapped_text:
    print(line.center(80))
```

Answer (score -1):

To add text to an image with padding on both sides (left and right) so that it automatically wraps, you can follow these steps using the PIL (Pillow) library:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# Load the image
image = Image.open("your_image.jpg")

# Define padding and text
padding = 70
text = "Your long text that needs to auto-wrap goes here."

# Create a drawing context
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# Load a font
font_size = 36  # Adjust the font size as needed
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", font_size)

# Calculate the maximum text width based on image width minus padding
max_text_width = image.width - 2 * padding

# Function to split text into lines that fit within the given width
def wrap_text(text, font, max_width):
    lines = []
    current_line = ""
    
    for word in text.split():
        test_line = current_line + ("" if current_line == "" else " ") + word
        test_size = draw.textsize(test_line, font=font)
        
        if test_size[0] <= max_width:
            current_line = test_line
        else:
            lines.append(current_line)
            current_line = word
    
    if current_line:
        lines.append(current_line)
    
    return lines

# Wrap the text
wrapped_lines = wrap_text(text, font, max_text_width)

# Calculate the total text height
text_height = sum([draw.textsize(line, font=font)[1] for line in wrapped_lines])

# Calculate the vertical position for centering the text
text_y = (image.height - text_height) // 2

# Draw the wrapped text on the image
for line in wrapped_lines:
    text_width, text_height = draw.textsize(line, font=font)
    text_x = (image.width - text_width) // 2
    draw.text((text_x, text_y), line, font=font, fill="white")
    text_y += text_height  # Move to the next line

# Save or display the image
image.save("output_image.jpg")
image.show()
```

In this code:

1. Load your image using `Image.open()`.
2. Define the padding (70 pixels) and the text you want to add.
3. Create a drawing context with `ImageDraw.Draw(image)`.
4. Load a font with the desired size using `ImageFont.truetype().`
5. Calculate the maximum text width based on the image width minus
   padding.
6. Implement a function `wrap_text()` to split the text into lines that
   fit within the maximum width.
7. Calculate the total text height and the vertical position for
   centering the text.
8. Draw the wrapped text on the image, centering it both vertically and
   horizontally.
9. Save or display the resulting image.

Make sure to replace `"your_image.jpg"` with the path to your image and adjust the `font size`, `font type`, and other parameters as needed.

Comment: did you use any AI to write any part of this answer?

Comment: @starball Yes, chatGPT was used for this. But I have personally tried it and presented it here. Because I was not successful using textwrap, I used an AI tool. But I will remove it if it violates the terms and conditions here. Sorry for the inconvenience.